# Inherited Control Visible/Enabled Property Value Always True: PropertyGrid

Tags: winforms, propertygrid, system.componentmodel, design-surface

I have created a custom WinForms hosting environment. Which has a toolbox and a PropertyGrid.

The controls displayed in the Toolbox are inherited from existing WinForm controls.

DropDownList Source:

```
public interface IPropertyFilter : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection FilterProperties(PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc);
    List<string> GetPropertiesToShow();
}

[Serializable]
public class DropDownList : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, IPropertyFilter
{
    public DropDownList()
    {
    }

    #region IPropertyFilter Members

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    EventDescriptorCollection System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public string GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, attributes, true);
        return FilterProperties(pdc);
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, true);
        return FilterProperties(pdc);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection FilterProperties(PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc)
    {
        // Filter out properties that we do not want to display in PropertyGrid
        return ControlDesignerHelper.GetBrowsableProperties(pdc, GetPropertiesToShow());
    }

    // Determines what properties of this control has to be shown in PropertyGrid
    public List<string> GetPropertiesToShow()
    {
        // get a list of common properties that we want to show for all controls
        List<string> browsableProps = ControlDesignerHelper.GetBasePropertiesToShow();
        // add properties that are specific to this controls
        browsableProps.Add("Items");
        browsableProps.Add("AutoPostBack");
        browsableProps.Add("AppendDataBoundItems");
        browsableProps.Add("DataTextField");
        browsableProps.Add("DataValueField");
        return browsableProps;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have implemented `ICustomTypeDescriptor` to filter out properties that I do not want to show in the `PropertyGrid`.

**Problem:**

I am facing problem while serializing values of `Enabled` & `Visible` properties that are inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class.

**WriteProperties Method (`BasicDesignerLoader`):**

```
private void WriteProperties(XmlDocument document, PropertyDescriptorCollection properties, object value, XmlNode parent, string elementName)
{
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop.Name);

        if (prop.ShouldSerializeValue(value))
        {
            string compName = parent.Name;
            XmlNode node = document.CreateElement(elementName);
            XmlAttribute attr = document.CreateAttribute("name");

            attr.Value = prop.Name;
            node.Attributes.Append(attr);

            DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute visibility = (DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute)prop.Attributes[typeof(DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute)];

            switch (visibility.Visibility)
            {
                case DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible:
                    if (!prop.IsReadOnly && WriteValue(document, prop.GetValue(value), node))
                    {
                        parent.AppendChild(node);
                    }

                    break;

                case DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content:
                    object propValue = prop.GetValue(value);

                    if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                    {
                        WriteCollection(document, (IList)propValue, node);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(propValue, propertyAttributes);

                        WriteProperties(document, props, propValue, node, elementName);
                    }

                    if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        parent.AppendChild(node);
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem # 1:** The `ShouldSerializeValue` method for the `Enabled` & `Visible` property always returns false.

**Problem # 2:** Even if I skip the `ShouldSerializeValue` method check the `GetValue` method of the `PropertyDescriptor` always returns `True`.

**Current Workaround:**
As a workaround I have currently made the `Enabled` & `Visible` properties hidden using the `BrowsableAttribute`, and created two other boolean properties and used the `DisplayNameAttribute` to change their display name to be `Enable` & `Visible`.

But for this workaround I have to write these snippets in every control.

**Am I missing something or doing anything wrong? Why are the `Enabled` & `Visible` property do not change?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a long discussion about this issue [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29389714/inheritedpropertydescriptor-vs-reflectedpropertydescriptor.aspx). (dead link, can't find a new one)

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.aspx) aldo makes this remark:

> The InheritedPropertyDescriptor class
>   modifies the default value of a
>   property, so that the default value is
>   the current value at object
>   instantiation. This is because the
>   property is inherited from another
>   instance. The designer defines
>   resetting the property value as
>   setting it to the value that was set
>   by the inherited class. This value may
>   differ from the default value stored
>   in metadata.

ShouldSerializeValue's return value is based on the difference between the current value and the default value so I think this is directly related to your problem.

I hope this will help you figure out what happens in your own context.